# I want to get a list of all Azure SQL PaaS Databases in my subscription via Powershell Query

Tags: powershell, azure-sql-database

This is what I have so far, but returns no output

```
function Get-SQLDatabase {
[CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        # Parameter help description
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]
        $path
    )

    $rg = Get-AzResourceGroup
    foreach($resourcegroup in $rg) {
        Get-AzSqlDatabase | export-csv -Path $path -Append
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to confirm, you do mean that there is no output to the path that you have defined for the CSV? Are you receiving any errors?

Comment: Yes, no output, no errors either. When I only do "Get-AzSqlDatabase", it asks for the server name, but I need it for all servers regardless. Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: I don't understand why you reversed my edit, I put code blocks in around your function so it's easier to read for others. To answer your query, you should loop through your Resource Groups, use `Get-AZSqlServer` to get the SQL Servers in the current Resource Group and then loop through the SQL Databases within the SQL servers.

Comment: @Ash Apologies, I did not realize those were edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Ash you need to enumerate your SQL servers within each Resource Group, which adds another loop within your loop.

```
function Get-SQLDatabase {
[CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        # Parameter help description
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]
        $path
    )

    $rg = Get-AzResourceGroup
    foreach($resourcegroup in $rg) {
        $SQLServers = Get-AzSqlServer -ResourceGroup $resourcegroup.ResourceGroupName
        ForEach($Server in $SQLServers){
            Get-AzSqlDatabase -Server $Server.ServerName | export-csv -Path $path -Append
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** This isn't working, so let's add some troubleshooting steps in here. There's a couple things you can do to help find the issue. You can add `-Verbose` to your `Get-Az*` cmdlets, or you can add in `Write-Verbose` lines in your loops to track things without having to cleanup the script later. Let's look at what that would look like here:

```
function Get-SQLDatabase {
[CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        # Parameter help description
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]
        $path
    )

    $rg = Get-AzResourceGroup

    Write-Verbose "Found the following Resource Groups: `n$rg"

    foreach($resourcegroup in $rg) {

        Write-Verbose "Enumerating SQL Servers in the resource group: $resourcegroup"

        $SQLServers = Get-AzSqlServer -ResourceGroup $resourcegroup.ResourceGroupName

        Write-Verbose "Found the following SQL Servers:`n$SQLServers"

        ForEach($Server in $SQLServers){

            Write-Verbose "Adding SQL databases to the CSV from SQL Server: $Server"

            Get-AzSqlDatabase -Server $Server.ServerName | export-csv -Path $path -Append
        }
    }
}
```

Once you have added all the verbose output to track things you can call the function with the `-Verbose` switch to see that output, or leave the `-Verbose` off to have it run quietly without that output.

```
Get-SQLDatabase -Path 'C:\Temp\SQL-DBs.csv' -Verbose
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the response, I tried this, it doesn't give errors but also doesn't produce a csv file at all.

Comment: @Jawaria, If you remove `| export-csv -Path $path -Append` does it print out the the SQL databases to the console?

Comment: You are executing the function after you run this code right? Something like `Get-SQLDatabase -path 'C:\Temp\SQLDBs.csv'` after running the above.

Comment: No, I tried that as well, no results come up.

Comment: Are you connected to your Azure subscription in PowerShell? `Connect-AzAccount` / `Get-AzContext`

Comment: Try adding `-Verbose` to your `Get-Az*` lines, so you can follow exactly what it's doing to better troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: Looks like it had to be connected again. I am however, getting the following error for the "Get-AzSqlServer" line "Get-AzSqlServer : Resource group 'Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.SdkModels.PSResourceGroup' could not be found."    Also, it states "WARNING: System.ArgumentException: Argument passed in is not serializable."

Comment: I updated the answer since it seems that those cmdlets want strings, not objects, so I specify the correct property for each parameter. See if that works better.

Comment: Seems as if the extra .ResourceGroupName, .ServerName, prompt for user input to the specific RG name, which is not ideal as I want them for the entire subscription.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, those are properties on the objects that were returned from previous cmdlets. Such as, `Get-AzResourceGroup` returns an object with several properties including `ResourceGroupName`. Honestly the entire function should be able to be reduced to `Get-AzResourceGroup | Get-AzSqlServer | Get-AzSqlDatabase | Export-Csv $path -append`